# Problems in Maui Android native Binding Kotlin with the methods "suspend fun"

Tags: kotlin, maui

We are doing a link in Maui .Net 6.0 from the native Kotlin library, the sync (fun) methods work, but the async (fun suspend) methods include the "IContinue Continue" parameter and we can't use it in maui.

Is there a way to call asynchronous methods from maui? We have tried to create the IContinue object but without success.

Thank you so much

Sample use the kotlin async method in Maui .net 6.0